# Join lines on a common field

Tags: shell

On a Linux system, I have a file:

Hello 4

Hello 9

Hello 21

World 2

World 6

How can I join these lines on the common first field, and produce the output like:

Hello 4 9 21

World 2 6

by using the common utilities of Linux

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: just read the manual of basic tools, not consider sed and awk yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a kind of database operation, namely a *select* and *group by* so a good tool to use for such a task would be awk

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=" "}{arr[$1]=arr[$1] " " $2 }END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' file
```

where `file` is your file

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2;}END{for( i in a) print i""a[i];}' YOUR_FILE_HERE
```

notice:

this only works with "space" seprated and "two fields" in a row

Answer (score 0):

My dear Boy, you will have to write yourself a `.sh` script:

1. Creating a .sh script : http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html
2. Reading a file : http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1757-how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line
3. Comparing strings : http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

or use the `awk` script that @amow wrote for you.

Good luck!